# Identity server retrieving user details

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I have been trying to implement identity server with my angular application by following [this tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client). I've found it really helpful so far.

I would like to get the users name plus a few custom details, but I cannot work out how to do it.

In the section

```
export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
    return {
        authority: 'http://localhost:5555/',
        client_id: 'angular_spa',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        response_type:"id_token token",
        scope:"openid profile api1",
        filterProtocolClaims: true,
        loadUserInfo: true
    };
}
```

I have made sure I have set `loadUserInfo: true`. But when I look at the contents of the returned object I can't see any user information.

[image: oicd object]

Do I need to do something on the server to return user firstname etc. I am currently using the TestUser class, but I expected to see Username in user.profile on the client. On the server my user is set up as

```
new TestUser {
    SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
    Username = "scott",
    Password = "password"
}
```

and as shown above I can see the `SubjectId` (although I find it odd that it is mapped to sub and not sid)

The way I understood the tutorial was that once logged successfully oicd-client would make another call to the server using the retrieved token, to get the users details when you set `loadUserInfo: true`

Why can't I see the details?

EDIT:

Looking through the tutorial again, I noticed this line:

> If loadUserInfo is set to true, it will also call the user info endpoint to get any extra identity data it has been authorized to access.

How do I authorize the user info endpoint  to get access to data I want it to access?

Comment: You can set AlwaysIncludeClaimsInIdToken to true in the client configuration and then you don’t need to bother with user info endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure what user data will be returned, I hadn't configured any!

In `Startup.cs` make sure you have the following:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                ...
                .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
                ...
    }
```

Then add `claims` to your user

```
public static List<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<TestUser> {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                Username = "scott",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("name", "scott"),
                    new Claim("website", "https://scott.com")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

the claims will then be present in the profile property on the client.